Why is overflow auto not working on IOS but on any other device?
I've developed an web application for ordering. The overflow of the menu content works fine on desktop and also on android devices.
For some reason on IOS, the scroll (overflow) is not working. I've tried some other issues like removing position: relative; attributes.
The container of the menu is wrapped in another container with overflow: hidden;.
If I change this parent container to overflow: auto; the scrolling works, but other logic like auto-scroll to a item, ... does no longer work, since the scrolling-element is no longer the intended one.
In the screenshot it works correctly (but on an actual ios device not)
The first arrow is the container with overflow: hidden;
The 2nd arrow is the menu-container with overflow: scroll;
The URL: https://flairorder.vercel.app/de/order/restaurant/664525aea9fe87b37f5f8073
Any ideas?


Seems that i've found an issue.
One wrapper in the chain had display:flex without flex-direction:column
As far as I know this should be default behaviour (works on desktop/android)
Somehow on IOS it only worked, after adding flex-direction:column to all containers in the chain
